# Unusual output for XSL transformations

Tags: java, xml, transformation, xslt

I have an xml document and a style sheet to convert the document into another useful xml. 
For the reference the xml document is somewhat like this:

```
<root>
 <element1>value1</element1>
 <element2>value2</element2>
 <element3>value3</element3>
 <element4>..some more levels of data</element4>
</root>
```

The style sheet looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="errorResponse.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="root/element4">
        <xsl:element name="myRoot">
            <xsl:element name="myElement">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./someElement/someOtherElement"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The output xml string which I am getting is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
value1
value2
value3
<myRoot><myelement> some data </myElemrnt></myroot>
```

The code snippet which I am using for transformation is this:

```
InputStream styleSheet = new FileUtil().getFileStream("xsltFileName");
StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(styleSheet);

DOMSource in = new DOMSource(inputXMLDoc);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transFact.setURIResolver(new XsltURIResolver());
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xslStream);
trans.transform(in, new StreamResult(baos));
System.out.println(baos.toString()); // displays the above output
```

However the output is in undesired format. I dont want value1, value2, value3. This is also creating problems further for the new XML generated, to be processed.

I have seen a lot of questions around the transformations. This is bugging me for a long time. Appreciate a lot if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

Also point out if I am following any incorrect conventions during the entire process.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What exact output do you expect from the stylesheet? Can't help you without that… Does the error also occur when using any other XSLT processor? Some browsers can do that for you, else use Saxon

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that output because of the [Default Template Rule](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch08_07.htm), which outputs the text nodes.  If you don't want those nodes you need to exclude them explicitly by matching them and replacing them with nothing (i.e. an empty template).

Try adding this template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element4"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It matches the root and discards everything except for `root/element4`.

Comment: I tried to match the root element and then templatize with the entire xpath. It works that way. Thank you so much.
I however have worked with a few xslts and I havent faced such issue with them. 
Can we turn off this default behaviour? Also what if I want this default behaviour to work, but should return the values within the nodes( and not as separate values ).

Comment: The default is not changeable, but you "turn it off" by matching the root and then selecting what you want to process. When you match the root you are taking control and the defaults won't apply unless you explicitly invoke them again with `<xsl:apply-templates>` and no other template matches the context at that point.

Answer (score 1):

**What happens here is that the XSLT [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule) are applied** to any node not matched explicitly by a template. The net effect of the built-in templates is to copy any text node (on which tey are applied) to the output.

**One of the simplest and shortest way to supress this unwanted output** is to add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

which causes any text-node for which this template is selected for execution, not to be copied to the output.